# Saving Tableview data in swift

Tags: swift

I'm currently working on a tableView based project in swift. I have two tableView running in my project. As my first tableView loaded with data which has a editActionsForRowAtIndexPath function to delete cell(as a Favourite) and moving it to my second tableview.I am using the following code.....

firstTableView:

```
var arrays = ["Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Phill","Below","Above","Clean",]
var deleted: [String] = []    
//passing data to another tableVC
var sendSelectedData = NSString()    
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Favourite") { action, index in
    print("favourite button tapped")
    let editingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete            
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.deleted.append(self.arrays[indexPath.row])
            self.arrays.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()             
        }
    }

    favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    return [favorite]        
}

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {   
if (segue.identifier == "ShowDetails") {        
    // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
    let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! favTableViewController
    // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
    viewController.arrayx = deleted        
}
}
```

Above code works as i planned. Every time, When the swipe action perform. that particular cell been moved to my second view controller.But, I am getting trouble saving data and reload `tableview`  on both my first and second `tableView` Controller after `tableViewCell` been moved to my second `tableView`...

I know `NSUserDefaults` function will save data.But, I am not familiar using `NSUserdefaults`.So,Please someone point me the direction...

thanks in Advance...

Comment: Realm.io (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) has the easiest learning curve IMO. Their docs are very comprehensive, and easy to navigate.

Answer (score -1):

NSUserdefaults should only be used for storing small amounts of data, ie: user defaults, and is not ideal for a table view, where in the real world you will have a lot of data to load and display.

Other native options are Coredata, Apple's database solution. Unfortunately it is a complex beast and a mere mortal such as I finds it a pain to use.

I highly recommend you investigate using Realm (https://realm.io/). It is a powerful database solution, well documented, and easy to use (and free!). If you want to learn how to integrate Realm into your project the following video will start you off with the absolute basics:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGXPqDX7dsw&nohtml5=False