# Reload Tableview in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm currently working on a tableView based project in swift. I have two tableView running in my project. As my first tableView loaded with data which has a editActionsForRowAtIndexPath function to delete cell(as a Favourite) and moving it to my second tableview.

But, I am getting trouble saving data and reloading tableview on both my first and second tableView Controller after tableViewCell been moved to my second tableView...

```
 var arrays = ["Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Phill","Below","Above","Clean",]
 var deleted: [String] = []    
 //passing data to another tableVC
 var sendSelectedData = NSString()    
 let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

 let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Favourite") { action, index in
 print("favourite button tapped")
 let editingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete            
 if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.deleted.append(self.arrays[indexPath.row])
        self.arrays.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()             
    }
}

favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
return [favorite]        
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {   
if (segue.identifier == "ShowDetails") {        
// initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as!      favTableViewController
// your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
viewController.arrayx = deleted        
}
}
```

I am not sure whether i have to use NSUserDefaults function to save data or just reload tableview..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Nobody else remains sure, either, unless you post code.

Comment: @ElTomato my partial code is in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514712/saving-tableview-data-in-swift

Comment: Do you have a disability such that you are not physically capable of posting your code or something?

Comment: @ElTomato.code uploaded as you wish...take a look....cheers

Comment: You have an extra comma that you don't need in your array.